# Why is the author citation of Polypodium porosum (C. Presl) Mett.?

Tags: botany, taxonomy

I would like to understand what constitutes a valid taxonomic description of a species in botany and by chance I encountered this example (which I otherwise know nothing about).

Either

[*Pyrrosia porosa* (C.Presl) Hovenkamp](https://www.gbif.org/species/7290046)

or

[*Polypodium porosum* (C. Presl) Mett.](https://tropicos.org/name/50051140)

Ignoring the issue which one of the above genus attribution is better, my question is why [the publication of C. Presl](https://www.biodiversitylibrary.org/item/14546#page/202/mode/1up) is the base when he only refers to the species by pointing to [*Polypodium porosum* Wall.](https://tropicos.org/name/50051139). However, that publication is considered invalid and [was published again by Mettenheimer](https://www.biodiversitylibrary.org/item/188339#page/140/mode/1up) (Tropicos seems to point to Band 1 in error). However, why is the citation *Polypodium porosum* (C. Presl) Mett. and not *Polypodium porosum* Wall. ex Mett. or *Pyrrosia porosa* (Wall ex Mett.) Hovenkamp? And why the synonym is *Niphobolus porosus* C.Presl and not ... I do not know what it would be when he just points to a name used in an invalid publication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you state, the designation from Wallich is not a valid name, and I don't think it was even effectively published (the work appears to be just a hand-written manuscript, not even an "indelible autograph" [International Code of Nomenclature for algae, fungi, and plants. [Article 30.6-30.6](https://www.iapt-taxon.org/nomen/pages/main/art_30.html)]). It does, however, indicate a specimen, #266.

Carl Presl both effectively and validly published *Niphobolus porosus* when he both pointed to a specimen (the one from Wallich) and provided a description on page 200.

> Fasiculi vasorum in stipite duro tres, teretes, minuti, juxta se aut in triangulum positi, medio seu posteriore minore, in N. poruso quator teretes aequales.

> [For *Niphobolus* generally:] Three bundles of hard, rounded stem, small, placed near each other or in a triangle, in the middle or smaller posterior, **in N. porusus four round smooth ones**.

Normally, this would lead to a citation of "*Niphobolus porosus* Wall. ex C. Presl", except in this case Wallich used the designation *Polypodium porosus* and Presl is using *Niphobolus porosum*. Since they're not the same combination, Wallich doesn't get credit ([Article 46.4](https://www.iapt-taxon.org/nomen/pages/main/art_46.html)). Article 46, Example 27 states:

> When publishing *Andropogon drummondii*, Steudel (Syn. Pl. Glumac. 1: 393. 1854) attributed the name to “Nees. (mpt. sub: *Sorghum*.)”. This reference to the unpublished binary designation “*Sorghum drummondii* Nees” is not ascription of *A. drummondii* to Nees, and the name is cited as *A. drummondii* Steud., not *A. drummondii* “Nees ex Steud.”

The combinations from Mettenius and Hovenkamp, therefore, use *Niphobolus porosum* C. Presl as the basionym.